# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and $x \in N_G(H)$. Prove that $P = \{hx^i | h\in H, i\in \Bbb Z\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and $x \in N_G(H)$. Prove that $$P = \{hx^i | h\in H, i\in\Bbb Z\}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I proved that $P$ is not empty because $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ so it's not empty and $N_G(H)$ is also not empty because $1$ commutes with every element in $H$.

I don't know how to show that $P$ is closed under $G$ operation and is closed under inverses.

To prove the former, I tried: Let $s$ and $t \in P$ so $s = h_1(x_1)^i$ and $t = h_2(x_2)^j$, so $st = h_1(x_1)^ih_2(x_2)^j$ but don't know how to show that belongs to $P$ also...

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

We have that every power $x^n$ normalizes $H$. Thus $Hx^n=x^nH$. Hence $(h_1x^i)(h_2x^j)=h_1h_3x^{i+j}=hx^{i+j}$, $h\in H$, so $P$ is closed under multiplication. Then $(hx^i)^{-1}=x^{-i}h^{-1}=h_1x^{-i}$. So $P$ is closed under taking inverses.

Answer (score 3):

There is a somewhat more general result of group theory at play here in this context and I would like to mention it explicitly. Recall that given any magma $(A, \cdot)$ -- i.e. a pair consisting of set $A$ equipped with an arbitrary binary operation $\cdot \colon A \times A \to A$ -- for any subsets $X, Y \subseteq A$ we define their subset product as $XY\colon=\{xy\}_{\substack{x \in X \\ y \in Y}}$. This allows us to consider the extension of the original operation "$\cdot$" on $A$ to the powerset $\mathscr{P}(A)$, as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\cdot \colon \mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(A) &\to \mathscr{P}(A)\\
\cdot(X, Y)\colon&=XY
\end{align}$$
If we equip the powerset with the standard order structure given by inclusion, the magma structure introduced above will be compatible with this order structure (i.e. will be an *ordered* magma) in the precise sense that for any subsets $X, Y, Z \subseteq A$ such that $X \subseteq Y$ the relations $XZ \subseteq YZ$ respectively $ZX \subseteq ZY$ hold.

If $(S, \cdot)$ is a semigroup -- i.e. the operation "$\cdot$" on $S$ is associative -- the extension to $\mathscr{P}(S)$ remains associative, in other words the induced structure $(\mathscr{P}(S), \cdot)$ will also be a semigroup.

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and $K, H \leqslant G$ be two subgroups. Then the subset product $KH \leqslant G$ is a subgroup if and only if the commutation relation $KH=HK$ holds.

*Proof.* In groups it is in general valid that $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$ for any subsets $X, Y \subseteq G$. Under the hypothesis that $KH \leqslant G$, since subgroups are equal to their own symmetrics (the symmetric of subset $X \subseteq G$ is $X^{-1}\colon=\left\{x^{-1}\right\}_{x \in X}$), we infer that $KH=\left(KH\right)^{-1}=H^{-1}K^{-1}=HK$.

Conversely, assuming the commutation relation $F\colon=KH=HK$ we have the relation $FF^{-1}=(KH)(KH)^{-1}=(KH)\left(H^{-1}K^{-1}\right)=K\left(HH^{-1}\right)K^{-1} \subseteq KHK^{-1}=HKK^{-1} \subseteq HK=F$, where we have appealed to the criterion according to which $E \subseteq G$ is a subgroup if and only if $E \neq \varnothing$ and $EE^{-1} \subseteq E$. Since $K, H \neq \varnothing$ we clearly have $F \neq \varnothing$ and thus the mentioned criterion applies to $F$ as well, to the effect that $F \leqslant G$.

---

The proposition applies immediately to your problem: given $H \leqslant G$ and $t \in \mathrm{N}_G(H)$ we have by definition that $L\colon=\{xt^n\}_{\substack{x \in H\\n \in \mathbb{Z}}}=H\langle t \rangle$, where $\langle X \rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by subset $X \subseteq G$ (with the abbreviation $\langle \{y\} \rangle=\langle y \rangle$ for any $y \in G$).

As $t \in \mathrm{N}_G(H)$ it follows that $\langle t \rangle=\{t^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \leqslant \mathrm{N}_G(H)$ and one can easily prove that more generally for *any* subgroup $K \leqslant \mathrm{N}_G(H)$ the relation $KH=HK$ is valid. Indeed, for any $y \in K$ we have by definition of the normaliser that $yH=Hy$ and thus $KH=\displaystyle\bigcup_{y \in K}yH=\displaystyle\bigcup_{y \in K}Hy=HK$.